# How to pause stream reader and replay stream in reverse VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have text file which I read "line by line" using following code:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
        MsgBox(TextLine)
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

I already have developed code that allows me to pause file reading (simple enable and disable timer seems to be good solution).
Question is:
What do I need to do  to read text file in reverse order starting from the line where stream reader was stopped/paused?

Thank you all very much. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't. You'd have to read the whole file into an array and loop through it backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was afraid off. Although files that I read are not very big, storing them into array (each line would be array element) may add additional processing time but that seems to be only option left to try. I don't want to start referencing external INI files. It woul make it even worse.

Comment: You really won't notice any performance difference, not unless your files are a couple of gigs in size.

Comment: No problem, have fun. :)